# Image Resizer not working on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image-resizing

I am using [ImageResizing.net](http://ImageResizing.net)
All of thing fine in my local but when I upload project on host, that not working
I use this plugin like this:

```
<img src="/Images/images/p2.jpg?w=360&h=240&mode=crop" class="img-responsive" />
```

But my images isn't displayed on server (not local).
Please help me!

Comment: This path looks pretty hardcoded to me: `/Images/images`. Could there be a virtual directory on your server? Also when you try to open this url directly on your browser what's the result? 404?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks for answer. There isn't virtual directory on server. When custom error is on and open this url I see my error page, but when custom error is off after open this url I see nothing (even error page) in my browser and see in console browser `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: So you should be checking the logs from your application to see what could be the potential cause for this 500 error. And what does the error page say? Maybe it contains an exception and a stacktrace?

Comment: I checked using elmah and I see this error: `Access to the path 'D:\HostingSpace\xxx.com\httpdocs\imagecache\024e' is denied`

Comment: OK, so now you know what the problem is and you know what you should be doing: granting the required permissions to the account under which your application is running to this folder. Is there something else you would like to ask about?

Comment: No, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, according to @Darin Dimitrov comments, I checked my project using Elmah and I found an error:

> Access to the path 'D:\HostingSpace\xxx.com\httpdocs\imagecache\024e' is denied

I am using Plesk panel and I forgot to grant read and write access to my httpdocs folder.

So, finally my problem was solved.